# source code manipulation(adding synchronized block) changes the variable scope

Tags: java, scope

I'm writing a path profiling tools, and i use jdt Astparser to modify the source code
If i want to add some codes after every original lines and let them to be atomic operations and don't change the behavior of the source code . just like this:
original source code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
a = b;
```

after manipulation

```
synchronized (lock) {
int a = 0;  //original code
//my code
//....
//end
}
synchronized (lock) {
int b = 0;  //original code
//my code
//....
//end
}
synchronized (lock) {
a = b;  //original code
//my code
//....
//end
}
```

but it changes the variable scope, the variable a and b are no longer global and the code can't compile.

Is there any method to combine the variable declaration and codes i inserted after that to let them become atomic operation and don't change the variable scope?

...and sorry for my english :)

Comment: If you don't want them in the scope of the block, don't declare them in the block.

Comment: I want the variable declaration and code i inserted after to be atomic operation so it must be in the block

Comment: @Brian Roach see above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare them in the block.  This has nothing to do with the initialisation itself.

```
int a, b;

synchronized (lock) {
    a = 0;
}
synchronized (lock) {
    b = 0;

}
synchronized (lock) {
    a = b; 
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using three `synchronized` blocks, though, unless the code is much more complex than your example suggests.

Comment: Actually i want to add some code after  "int a, b;"  and they should be atomic

Comment: Writing `int a, b;` simply declares them in the current scope.  You can access them from your `synchronized` blocks, and do whatever operations you want.